# UICollectionView 2 Different Background Colors

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I try to avoid the white background color on top of my collectionview cell if the user scrolls down (basicly when it bounced). So on top of my cell is only the collectionview background color visible. But as shown in the picture I need 2 different colors. For the first section the background should be blue so the gap isn't white but blue and for the other sections it should remain white. So all I want is that the gap in white will become blue without changing the complete backgroundcolor of my uicollectionview.

[image]

Comment: Don't know about your view hierarchy but you could maybe try to set blue color on this `self.view.backgroundColor` or this `self.collectionView.superview.backgroundColor`.

Comment: That does not work because the collectionview takes the whole screensize. And has white background color, so nothing would be visible from the superview.

Comment: Why do not set blue background color to the `collectionView` and then change the sections individually ?

Comment: Because then I have the same problem on the bottom. The gap would be blue, but on the bottom it should remain white!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by adding a view to the top your UICollectionView or UITableView - it will be scrolled along with the content and will appear as part of the background.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let topView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -collectionView!.bounds.height,
        width: collectionView!.bounds.width, height: collectionView!.bounds.height))
    topView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
    collectionView!.addSubview(topView)
}
```

Comment: @maxkonovalov how would you do this for the bottom area?

Comment: @skyguy never tried this, but I think the same approach should be fine, just calculate the frame appropriately based on `contentSize`