# Changing ListView bounce color when using iOS behavior in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

When creating a `ListView` ([example from docs](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/basic-list)), how do we change the bounce color that appears at the top of the list when scrolling using an iOS emulator with Flutter?

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.map),
      title: Text('Map'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
      title: Text('Album'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
      title: Text('Phone'),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525445/uicollectionview-2-different-background-colors), in iOS development without Flutter, you would do something like this to position a view offscreen to change the bounce color:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let topView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -collectionView!.bounds.height,
        width: collectionView!.bounds.width, height: collectionView!.bounds.height))
    topView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
    collectionView!.addSubview(topView)
}
```

Is there an equivalent for Flutter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Flutter the bouncing color, is simply the color of the Widget you can see behind the [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html). The default background of the `ListView` is transparent.
Therefore you can simply wrap it in a [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) with another color.

The following example has a green bouncing color:

[image: Bouncing in green]

And the **complete** source code, for trying out:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: ListView(
              children: generateChildren()
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> generateChildren() {
    List<Widget> result = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      result.add(Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.map),
          title: Text('Map'),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: But the color of the listview body also changes, can i avoid it?