# Flutter : How to set background color for BouncingScrollPhysics?

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

When i set `BouncingScrollPhysics` for `SingleChildScrollView`, the backgound appears to be `white` when it bounces. Is there any way to change it to custom colors?

Comment: refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383810/changing-listview-bounce-color-when-using-ios-behavior-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the background color of the Widget over which you are rendering SingleChildScrollView Widget. If your SingleChildScrollView is directly under Scaffold, then set `backgroundColor` property of your Scaffold to the color you desire.

Comment: But the color of the scaffold body changes with it. Can i avoid it?

Comment: That is the purpose of changing the Scaffold background color. Moreover it depends on how you've laid your widgets on tree. A sample code will help

Comment: Ok got it , Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colours.background,
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ....
          ],
        ),
      ),
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    ));
```